# Is it possible to include digest credentials in nginx conf?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, digest-authentication

I'm trying to run some automation tests against a network that requires digest authentication.
With curl I would do:

> curl --digest -u user:pass -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d data https://URL

With python:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
authentication = HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass')
```

I would like to run an nginx reverse proxy though, add the credentials there and access the network without further authentication:

```
server {
  listen 8555;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;   
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on; 
    proxy_pass https://URL;
  }
}
```

With Basic authorization you can do:

> proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic a4luZzppc25ha2Vk";

But how can I do that with digest authorization?

Comment: Are you permitted to compile nginx from source? If so, you could download the [nginx-http-auth-digest](https://github.com/samizdatco/nginx-http-auth-digest) module. I've used it, but it's been a while.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have done that, but that module protects the listener with digest authentication. I want to be able to send requests to my listener (localhost:8545) and nginx to provide the authentication for the remote server.